# Mysql not connecting to server through php

Tags: php, mysql, database, server

I have been trying to connect to the mysql server through php code, but was unable to. Please help me solve this problem.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $email    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $fname    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $lname    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$bool = true;
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root","rot_darshan") or die("Cannot connect to server"); //Connect to server
    mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database
    $query = mysql_query("Select * from users"); //Query the users table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) //display all rows from query
    {
            $table_users = $row['username']; // the first username row is passed on to $table_users, and so on until the query is finished
            if($username == $table_users) // checks if there are any matching fields
            {
                    $bool = false; // sets bool to false
                    Print '<script>alert("Username has been taken!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
                    Print '<script>window.location.assign("register.php");</script>'; // redirects to register.php
            }
    }
    if($bool) // checks if bool is true
    {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password,fname,lname,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$fname','$lname','$email')"); //Inserts the value to table users
            Print '<script>alert("Successfully Registered!");</script>'; // Prompts the user
            Print '<script>window.location.assign("register.php");</script>'; // redirects to register.php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Stop using mysql_ functions. They are insecure and deprecated! Please use mysqli, PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: what's the error u are getting

Comment: As Ben said, you should use mysqli_ or PDO_ - mysql is deprecated and not longer supported in PHP7. Also, please share you error with us. "I'm unable to connect" isn't a good error description. Tell us WHAT is wrong. Copy paste your error message.

Comment: One of the problem might be wrong credentials. Do you mind to post your error. Even try out this mysql_connect('domain_name.com:3306', 'user', 'password'); Make sure you give the proper domain name and check once if the PORT is appropriate. Some times there might be even port issue

Comment: @rahulpatel@Twinfriends when i execute in web-browser, its showing fields to enter data, but after entering the data, data is not stored anywhere, i created mysql db, and table as first_db users respectively. i double checked the columns its correct as it should be.

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari i checked the domainname as well as port . they are correct

Comment: i m afraid i m getting no error messages in terminal or web browser, all my php files reside in /var/www/html/website/*.

Comment: @darshanan.24 I think the display_error are suppressed can you please enable the display_error option in your page : ini_set('display_errors',1);
            ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
            error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

Comment: HI @darshanan.24 even I tried to do that from localhost but didn't achieve anything. Alternatively, you can push the file to the server /var/www/html/scripts/script_name.php and run that script from your browser url by giving http://domain_name/scripts/script_name.php. Where your host will be localhost only

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid the native mysql_* functions. These are depricated and will be removed:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Try to follow (mysqli_*):
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "rot_darshan";
$database = "first_db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Query example
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users")
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["username"]);
}
```

If these don't work, check your database credentials (username, password, database name and/or port)

Comment: i ll give a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Check for username,password by externally connecting .also replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 or your lan ip.
Check SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;